# Can I __destruct() a library object in CodeIgniter 2.1?

Tags: php, destructor, codeigniter-2

I am using the CodeIgniter 2.1 PHP framework. I have a library file that manipulates a User object. The object refers to a specific user record in my database. I want to be able to delete this record and destroy the object so that it cannot be erroneously accessed after it's destruction. Normally, one would employ the `__destruct()` function but upon my initial investigation I am not sure if I can use this function in a CI library object. Is this possible? Are there reasons why I shouldn't use the `__destruct()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load a library, its extended to the controller (then by `CI_base` and then `CI_loader`). CI_Loader lasts indefinitely (all the way to end of script) and doesn't release its pointers  so `__destruct` will never be invoked.

I suggest manually including the file so you can utilize PHP Classes as its intended. `get_instance()` is already available once the controller is available so you still have access to CI if you put the include to your class above the controller class and you wont be restricted to `$this->load->library();`

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. Thank you.